# Access pending Microsoft Outlook email with C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am currently working with an application that sends a local email with Outlook as default. The problem i am having is the fact that the application opens the email dialog box and the user has to manually click the send button which is what i am trying to avoid. I have been able to successfully access items in inbox and drafts however when the application opens dialog box Outlook does not automatically save as draft and I am unable to access the pending email. The following code is what i have used to access inbox and draft items. If anyone has come across a similar situation and advice would be much appreciated.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items items;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items draftItems;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns; 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder drafts;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        app = application;
        ns =  application.Session;
        drafts = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
        inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        items = inbox.Items;
        draftItems = drafts.Items;
        string test;


        foreach (Object _obj in draftItems)
        {
            if (_obj is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem blah = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)_obj);
                blah.Send();
            }
        }

        foreach (Object _obj in items)
        {
            if (_obj is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem blah = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)_obj);
                if (blah.UnRead)
                {
                    test = blah.Subject.ToString();
                    test = blah.Body.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to send email without using Outlook, or is Outlook a required third-party, or, am I missing the problem all together?

Comment: i am wanting to send email with c# with outlook as default email client.

Comment: Is using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient an option, or are you stuck with using third party dependencies (i.e. Outlook)?

Comment: Yes that would be an option. The problem is accessing the pending email. For more context i am using a live pdf to send the email the problem is the fact that it just opens default client without actually sending the email. In other words the user has to manually click send.

Comment: I guess I'm getting stuck on the pending emails part of your question.  When using SmtpClient, you specify the server details and message details and it sends the message behind the scenes, no user interaction, and no pending messages.

Comment: Yeah problem is that live pdf uses javascript behind the scenes which is unable to do that. The javascript is the following: event.target.app.mailMsg({bUI: true, cTo: Mailto, cSubject: subject, cMsg: body});
 Which opens dialog and everything works fine except for fact that user has to click send.

Comment: I'm even more confused now, your question (and code snippet) implies you are using C# for your send function? ... Or I'm missing something

Comment: No the c# is just showing i can access items in drafts and inbox. The actual sending is using javascript which is code behind for adobe live cycle designer.

Comment: Is olFolderOutbox the same as what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what the problem is. Call Aplication.CreaateItem(0) (returns MailItem object), set the subject and body, add recipients, and call MailItem.Send.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a [complete guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168346(v=office.11).aspx) on this.